# Set appearance for UIButton in appdelegate - setClipsToBounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to style all of the UIButtons in my app, but get an error when I setClipsToBounds.

Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter

I put this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the app delegate.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.314 green:0.745 blue:0.62 alpha:1]];

    [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [UIButton appearance].layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    [[UIButton appearance] setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

I want to make make the corners rounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `[UIButton appearance].clipsToBounds = YES;` and I get no crash. `clipsToBounds` is a `property`, not a `method`, but you are calling it like a method, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score -2):

A better way to style all buttons would be to assign tags to all buttons in a certain range and add this code:

```
for (int i=20; i<lastButtonTag; i++) 
{
  UIButton* button = (UIButton*) [self viewWithTag:i];
  // add more styling here
  button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
  button.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Where do I set the tag of the buttons using the storyboard?  I don't see it in the Identity and Attributes Inspectors.  Also, I put the code in the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method and get an error saying no visible method for [self viewWithTag:i]

Comment: I figured out where the tag option is - On the attribute pane, scroll down to View. Hover over it and you'll see on the right it shows Show. Click on it and it will expand and show you the Tag value.  But, I still get the error for [self viewWithTab...]

Comment: Sorry, my bad you can call viewWithTag on an object of type UIView. So create a property (eg: @property (weak) IBOutlet NSView *myview;) in appdelegate.h synthesize it in .m, connect this to your view in storyboard and do something like : [myview viewWithTag:i].

Comment: Is this only for one view in the app?  I want to set the style for all buttons in the entire app.  How would I do that?  I thought it was using [UIButton appearance], however I get the error I posted at the line [[UIButton appearance] setClipsToBounds:YES];  The other style attributes from my post seem to work.  I just can't get the edges to be rounded.

Comment: I tried what you said, but the compiler made me change the property to @property (weak) IBOutlet UIView *myview;  myview is nil when I step through the code and doesn't get a button.

Comment: Did you connect myView to storyboard view?

Comment: I guess that's the part I'm not too clear on.  How do you do that?